# Recursive TreeView creation with the data provided in this question?

Tags: java, recursion, javafx, treeview

I have a Treeview `TreeView<MyType>` which I'd like to fill recursively from a `MyType` root object. The structure of the class `MyType` is the following:

```
public class MyType {

    private Set<MyType> children = new HashSet<>();

    public Set<MyType> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }

    public void setChildren(Set<MyType> children) {
        this.children = children;
    }

}
```

So as you can see, the `MyType` root/parent has children of the same type, and those children can also have children from the same type. In practice, the depth between the root and its furthermost inheritant is no greater than 1000 level.

I want to fill the Treeview `TreeView<MyType>` recursively with tree items `TreeItem<MyType>`in the same tree structure as the data is stored in the `MyType` root file.

This is what I've tried so far but it's not working:

```
void buildTree(MyType parent, TreeItem<MyType> result) {
    for (MyType child : parent.getChildren()) {
        if (child.getChildren() == null || child.getChildren().isEmpty()) {
            result.getChildren().add(new TreeItem<MyType>(child));
        }

        else {
            TreeItem<MyType> tmp = new TreeItem<>(child);
            buildTree(child, tmp);
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to make the filling work with the data structure provided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's more convenient to

A. Return `TreeItem`s instead of passing both `MyType` and `TreeItem` to the recursive method calls.

B. Treat leafs as terminal cases instead of handling terminal cases at parents of leafs

This allows you to write the following code:

```
private TreeItem<MyType> buildSubtree(MyType root) {
    TreeItem<MyType> result = new TreeItem<>(root);

    if (root.getChildren() != null) {
        for (MyType child : root.getChildren()) {
            result.getChildren().add(buildSubtree(child));
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I just figured it out. This is working as expected.

```
void buildTree(MyType parent, TreeItem<MyType> result) {
        for (MyType child : parent.getChildren()) {
            if (child.getChildren() == null || child.getChildren().isEmpty()) {
                result.getChildren().add(new TreeItem<MyType>(child));
            }

            else {
                TreeItem<MyType> tmp = new TreeItem<>(child);
                buildTree(child, tmp);
                result.getChildren().add(tmp);
            }
        }
    }
```